# Error:class interface or enum expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Im using java and keep getting the error:class interface or enum expected. Here is the program, the compiler says the problem is on the last line but i can't figure it out.

```
    public class Ch3_PrExercise6 

        {
            static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
            public static void main(String [] args)
                throws Exception
            {
                final double FEDERAL_TAX_RATE = 0.15;
                 final double STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.035;
                final double SOCIAL_SECURITY_TAX_RATE = 0.575;
                final double MEDICARE_MEDICAID_TAX_RATE = 0.0275;
                final double PENSION_PLAN = 0.05;
                final double HEALTH_INSURANCE = $75;


            String name;
            double GrossAmount;
            double FederalTax;
            double StateTax;
            double SocialSecurityTax;
            double MedicareMedicaidTAx;
            double PensionPlan;
            double HealthInsurance;
            double NetPay;

            system.out.print("Bill Robinson");
            name = console.nextline();
            system.out.println();
            system.out.println(name);

            grossAmount = console.nextDouble();

            federalTAx = grossAmount * FEDERAL_TAX_RATE;
            stateTax= grossAmount * STATE_TAX_RATE;
            SocialSecurityTax = grossAmount * SOCIAL_SECURITY_TAX_RATE;
            MedicareMedicaidTax = grossAmount * MEDICARE_MEDICAID_TAX_RATE;
            PensionPlan = grossAmount * PENSION_PLAN_RATE;
            HealthInsurance = $75;

            NetPay= grossAmount - federalTax - stateTax - SocialSecurityTax - MedicareMedicaidTax - PensionPlan - HealthInsurance;

                PrintWriter outfile = new Printwriter("Ch3_Ex6out.txt");
                    outFile.printf ("Bill Robinson");
                    outFile.printf ("%n grossAmounT:            $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n federalTax              $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n stateTax                $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n SocialSecurityTax       $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n MedicareMedicaidTax     $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n Pension Plan            $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n HealthInsurance         $%8.2F");
                    outFile.printf ("%n NetPay                  $%8.2F");


                outFile.close();
        } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: You have got more than one issues in this file. e.g $75 is not valid literal over here. You can not use  system.out.println(); like this. Look at the "s" should be "S" at the start of system

Comment: Looks like you got one too many closing braces too

Comment: You have to make sure your variable names are used consistently. You have one defined as `GrossAmount` (capital G) but then later on you use it as `grossAmount` (lowercase G).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will compile... But you need to correct logic.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch3_PrExercise6 {
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main() throws Exception {
        final double FEDERAL_TAX_RATE = 0.15;
        final double STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.035;
        final double SOCIAL_SECURITY_TAX_RATE = 0.575;
        final double MEDICARE_MEDICAID_TAX_RATE = 0.0275;
        final double PENSION_PLAN = 0.05;
        final double HEALTH_INSURANCE = 75;

        String name;
        double grossAmount;
        double federalTAx;
        double stateTax;
        double SocialSecurityTax;
        double MedicareMedicaidTax;
        double PensionPlan;
        double HealthInsurance;
        double NetPay;

        System.out.print("Bill Robinson");
        name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(name);

        grossAmount = console.nextDouble();

        federalTAx = grossAmount * FEDERAL_TAX_RATE;
        stateTax = grossAmount * STATE_TAX_RATE;
        SocialSecurityTax = grossAmount * SOCIAL_SECURITY_TAX_RATE;
        MedicareMedicaidTax = grossAmount * MEDICARE_MEDICAID_TAX_RATE;
        PensionPlan = grossAmount * PENSION_PLAN;
        HealthInsurance = 75;

        NetPay = grossAmount - federalTAx - stateTax - SocialSecurityTax
                - MedicareMedicaidTax - PensionPlan - HealthInsurance;

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Ch3_Ex6out.txt");
        outFile.printf("Bill Robinson");
        outFile.printf("%n grossAmounT:            $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n federalTax              $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n stateTax                $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n SocialSecurityTax       $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n MedicareMedicaidTax     $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n Pension Plan            $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n HealthInsurance         $%8.2F");
        outFile.printf("%n NetPay                  $%8.2F");

        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but -1 for just posting "corrected" code without explaining what you did to correct it.